# How should I pass data from backend to a frontend js file in node.js & express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, backend

In my `index.js`, I get some `timeID` from database, and stored them as array `idContainer`, I want to pass this array `idConainer` to frontend `table.js` and compare the variable there.

In my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysqlConnect = require('./mysqlconnect')

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;

app
.use(morgan('short'))
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
.use(express.static('./public'))
app
.get('/get_time', (req, res) => {
    let idContainer = [];
    mysqlConnect.connection.query('SELECT * FROM testTable', (err, result, fields) => {
        if (!err) {
            Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
                let row = result[key];
                idContainer.push(row.timeID);
            });
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(idContainer)
    })
})
```

The file `table.js` is the one that I want to pass my data to. I want to check if `cellID` is equal to `timeID`. And here I get stuck with.

```
function tableBody() {
let tr; 
let td; 
let tblBodyContent = document.getElementById('tableBodyContent');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr')
    for (let col = 0; col < 6; col++) { 
        if (col === 5 && i > 5) break; 
        td = document.createElement('td')
        td.innerHTML = 'cell value here';
        let cellID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        td.setAttribute('id', cellID);
        td.addEventListener('click', cellClick);
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tblBodyContent.appendChild(tr);
}}
```

So to sum up, I want to pass data from backend to frontend js file, When I search this, I found a lot of articles talking about react.js.

1. Do I need to use react.js to handle this? or does it make this kind of transfer easier?
2. Can I do this with what I have now, meaning node.js and express?
3. and last, When I see this table from client side, I want this backend process done automatically, so in the table, if a `cellID == timeID`, I want that cell shows occupied without refresh the page, What is my direction?

Comment: In your backend you need to do `res.json(idContainer);` in order to send back a response to the client. In your client-side JS you do `fetch("/get_time").then(r => r.json()).then(data => { ... });` and in there, use `data` to do whatever you need to do. (1. you absolutely do not need React for any of this btw, and it doesn't make anything easier; you'd still have to do the same things I outlined 2. yes 3. manipulate the DOM in the `.then()` callback)

Comment: @Chris G, This works perfectly. seen fetch in different documents many times, but this is my first time using it. a lot to catch. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome :)